# The lost colony of Roanoke site

Tags: usa, history, north-carolina

From what I gather on my search there is a recreation of facilities and fortifications of the [Lost Colony of Roanoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roanoke_Colony).

I am wondering if the original buildings or fortifications still exist on the [Roanoke Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roanoke_Island) and can be visited?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The site of the original settlement on Roanoke Island has never been definitively located, and there is [disagreement among archeologists](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2004/03/0302_040302_lostcolony_2.html) as to where it lies. It is very possible that the site is underwater, as estimates of shoreline erosion on the north side of the island range [up to a quarter mile](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-8306.1972.tb00875.x#.UunZT_ldUpk), and even if not, it is likely that nature quickly reclaimed whatever structures the early colonists had managed to erect.

[Fort Raleigh National Historic Site](http://www.nps.gov/fora/) has exhibits related to the colony, but is situated at its namesake Civil War-era fort, noted for its [Freedmen's Colony](http://www.roanokefreedmenscolony.com/). This is also where performances of *[The Lost Colony](http://thelostcolony.org/)* are staged.